# NullPointerException related to hidden Swing GUI elements

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, swingbuilder

https://github.com/carlb710/myProgram

I'm using IntelliJ Swing GUI editor to make the front-end of my program. Based on the int value returned by a spinner, certain elements of the GUI are shown or hidden. Every time I change that int value and restart the program, one of many exceptions is thrown, all NullPointer Exceptions. I think they are always in the same thread, it's just the reason that varies.

Error usually looks something like these below:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "top" because "topInsets" is null
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.rotateInsets(AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.java:2000)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.getTabAreaInsets(AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.java:1681)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneUI$AquaTruncatingTabbedPaneLayout.superCalculateTabRects(AquaTabbedPaneUI.java:1133)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneUI$AquaTruncatingTabbedPaneLayout.calculateTabRects(AquaTabbedPaneUI.java:1091)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI$TabbedPaneLayout.calculateLayoutInfo(AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.java:2322)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI$TabbedPaneLayout.layoutContainer(AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.java:2226)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1538)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1527)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1723)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1658)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.ensureCurrentLayout(AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.java:1335)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneUI.paint(AquaTabbedPaneUI.java:148)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5271)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:75)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:112)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2003)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3949)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

The exceptions seem to be thrown when I run the following code in my main class to create the JFrame instance for my program:

```
 App window = null;
    try{
        window = new App();
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java QA Checker");
    frame.setContentPane(window.landing);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 16);
```

My GUI constructor looks like this where I think the issue is coming from:

````java
//listener for spinner, changes number of elements on screen
        spinner1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                numOfFiles = (Integer) spinner1.getValue();

//switch statement sets number of elements for file settings visible or not based on spinner value up to 12
                try {
                    switch(numOfFiles){
                        case 0:{
                            file1OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file3OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file4OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file5OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file6OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file7OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file8OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file9OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file10OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file11OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file12OriginLabel.setVisible(true);

                            file1OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file3OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file4OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file5OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file6OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file7OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file8OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file9OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file10OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file11OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file12OriginInputted.setVisible(true);

                            addFileButton1.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton2.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton3.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton4.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton5.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton6.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton7.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton8.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton9.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton10.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton11.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton12.setVisible(true);

                            filePathLabel1.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel2.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel3.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel4.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel5.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel6.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel7.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel8.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel9.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel10.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel11.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel12.setVisible(true);
                        } break;
                        case 1:{
                            file1OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file3OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file4OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file5OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file6OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file7OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file8OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file9OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file10OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file11OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file12OriginLabel.setVisible(false);

                            file1OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file3OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file4OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file5OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file6OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file7OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file8OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file9OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file10OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file11OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file12OriginInputted.setVisible(false);

                            addFileButton1.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton2.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton3.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton4.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton5.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton6.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton7.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton8.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton9.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton10.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton11.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton12.setVisible(false);

                            filePathLabel1.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel2.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel3.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel4.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel5.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel6.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel7.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel8.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel9.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel10.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel11.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel12.setVisible(false);
                        }break;
                        case 2:{
                            file1OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file3OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file4OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file5OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file6OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file7OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file8OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file9OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file10OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file11OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file12OriginLabel.setVisible(false);

                            file1OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file3OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file4OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file5OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file6OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file7OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file8OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file9OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file10OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file11OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file12OriginInputted.setVisible(false);

                            addFileButton1.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton2.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton3.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton4.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton5.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton6.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton7.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton8.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton9.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton10.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton11.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton12.setVisible(false);

                            filePathLabel1.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel2.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel3.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel4.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel5.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel6.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel7.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel8.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel9.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel10.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel11.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel12.setVisible(false);


                        } break;
                        case 3:{
                            file1OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file3OriginLabel.setVisible(true);
                            file4OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file5OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file6OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file7OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file8OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file9OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file10OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file11OriginLabel.setVisible(false);
                            file12OriginLabel.setVisible(false);

                            file1OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file2OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file3OriginInputted.setVisible(true);
                            file4OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file5OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file6OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file7OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file8OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file9OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file10OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file11OriginInputted.setVisible(false);
                            file12OriginInputted.setVisible(false);

                            addFileButton1.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton2.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton3.setVisible(true);
                            addFileButton4.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton5.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton6.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton7.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton8.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton9.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton10.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton11.setVisible(false);
                            addFileButton12.setVisible(false);

                            filePathLabel1.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel2.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel3.setVisible(true);
                            filePathLabel4.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel5.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel6.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel7.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel8.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel9.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel10.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel11.setVisible(false);
                            filePathLabel12.setVisible(false);
                        }break;
                        case 4:{..
                        } break;
//this goes until case 12, each just continues to make one more item .setVisible = true until all 12 elements are visible.
                        default: break;
                    }
                } catch(NullPointerException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(landing);
                }


                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(landing);


            }
        });

//additional code here that shouldn't be relevant to the issue
    } ```
````

Comment: Added the entire stack trace. To be honest, this is as minimal as I can get it since I'm really not sure where exactly it's going wrong other than what I have already described. As far as I can tell the exception occurs during the construction of the JFrame that everything lives in, but the error occasionally does not occur, usually when the spinner int value that I referred to in the original post has not been changed between program restarts. I don't know much more than that, I've been stuck on this for a while... I can't figure out where to catch the exception since it keeps changing.

Comment: The stack trace does not appear to contain any of your code. It looks to me that the problem is with the look-and-feel that you are using. You need to debug your app. I found [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/shenandoah/blob/master/src/java.desktop/macosx/classes/com/apple/laf/AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI.java) for class `com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneCopyFromBasicUI`. I'm just guessing but this line may be returning null: `tabAreaInsets = UIManager.getInsets("TabbedPane.tabAreaInsets");`

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was coming from the Main class that instantiated my GUI. I set the look and feel after creating the JFrame, when it should have been done before creating any GUI elements. This fixed my problem